# Displaying article with comments like Medium app

Tags: ios, uitableview, webkit

In my **iOS** Application, I want to display dynamic size article followed by comments like performed in **Medium** app. This article can have videos and text in random order. I am trying to use **UITableView** to accomplish this task. Inside my custom table view cell, there is **WKWebView**, where I'm displaying web content. I'm checking content size for **WKWebView** using its property

```
webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
```

It returns height in delegates for some of the URLs but sometime it return content height 0. Some time it loads only half page.
So I have some questions regarding this task:

1) Is it best approach to use **UITableView** for this purpose ? If it is not good then what should be alternative.

2) I am using **WebKit** to display web content. It works fine when I'm displaying data inside view controller but it's behaviour is different when it is inside **UITableViewCell**. Inside UITableViewCell, it takes while to load page, it doesn't load full page, sometime it doesn't load page at all. So is it recommended to use WebKit inside UITableViewCell ? If it is good approach then how can i get rid of these problems

Answer (score 0):

```
extension ContentViewController:  WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    //webview content cell

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        //        print("didCommitNavigation");

        //        if webView.isLoading == true {
        //            self.contentSize = 300
        //            return
        //        }



        let javascriptString = "" +
            "var body = document.body;" +
            "var html = document.documentElement;" +
            "Math.max(" +
            "   body.scrollHeight," +
            "   body.offsetHeight," +
            "   html.clientHeight," +
            "   html.offsetHeight" +
        ");"

        webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptString) { (result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                //                print(result as! CGFloat)
                guard result is CGFloat else {
                    return
                }

                self.contentSize =   result as! CGFloat

                if self.contentSize < 300 {
                    self.contentSize = 300
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tableView?.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView?.endUpdates()

                })
            }
        }


    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {


        let javascriptString = "" +
            "var body = document.body;" +
            "var html = document.documentElement;" +
            "Math.max(" +
            "   body.scrollHeight," +
            "   body.offsetHeight," +
            "   html.clientHeight," +
            "   html.offsetHeight" +
        ");"


        webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptString) { (result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                //                print(result as! CGFloat)
                //                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false


                let finishContentSize = result as! CGFloat

                if self.contentSize == finishContentSize {
                    return
                }

                //                self.tableView.height
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.contentSize =   finishContentSize

                    self.tableView?.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView?.endUpdates()
                })


            }

        }
    }

 }
```

you can get content height using javascript